# Logout after inactivity with php AND js

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, authentication

I have this php code to log out after 30 Minutes of inactivity in my index.php:

```
<?php 
    
    session_start(); /* Starts the session */

    if(!isset($_SESSION['UserData']['Username'])){
        header("location:login.php");
        exit;
    }
    else
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY']) && (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > 1800)) { 
        // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
        session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
        session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
        header("location:login.php?session_timeout");
        exit;
        }
        $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp
    }
?>
```

This code is on top of every protected page. As long as I reload this page the inactivity counter is updated, and also the logout does happen.

The problem is, all the other code in my webpage is written in js and jQuery, so the page never really get's refreshed, and so does the php code never executes. That leads to an not updated inactivity tiemer and I also don't get logged out.

Is there a possibility to change this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the JS make reasonably frequent AJAX requests? If so you can check the session status on every AJAX request too, and send back an error response if it's expired. And then the JS which receives that error could update the page / force it to refresh, or whatever.

Comment: You could set a timer in JS and have it check and logout as needed.